# Help with Open GL iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl, drawing, uiimageview

I am trying to put an OpenGL View into my application but I want to make sure that before I do this that the view is transparent because I want to see and interact with the view behind it as well as the OpenGL View. Meaning I want to have something on an OpenGL View as well as the Image View behind it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a view with a clear background and see the views behind it but you will not be able to have the user interact with the views that are behind.

Set the background color to [UIColor clearColor]

Comment: But that was my main problem. If you can use OpenGL in a UIImageView that would be great because that is in the end what I am trying to accomplish.